# Draw triangle in corner of div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to draw some kind of triangle in the corner of a div. Because I don't want to use "px" I'd like to achieve the same result also with percentage values.

This is what it should looks like:

[image: img]

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 5%; 
  left: 5%; 
  width: 60%; 
  height: 30%; 
  background: black; 
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 90%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` on triangle element and set `top` and `right` properties to 0.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #608A32 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

You can also just use `pseudo-element` with `absolute` position for triangle.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #608A32 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Below is another example with triangles in all corners.

```css
.all_triangles_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle_tl {
  border-width: 0 0 30px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.triangle_tr {
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.triangle_br {
  border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
  border-color: transparent yellow transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.triangle_bl {
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent purple transparent;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="all_triangles_container">
  <div class="triangle triangle_tl"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle_tr"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle_br"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle_bl"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can simply rely on background and create the triangle with a `linear-gradient` without extra markup and pseudo-element:

```css
.container { 
  width: 400px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg,#608A32 35px,#000 0); 
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696143/8620333

Comment: This is definitely best answer, overflow: hidden + pseudoelement causes problems sometimes (there is 1px gap between triangle and rest of element) when the background of parent element is transparent).

Answer (score 4):

The trick is make a square with `position:absolute` first and then use `top` and `right` position negative values(*equal to the half of width of the element*) to adjust it and then rotate it using `transform`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another way to use gradients backgrounds

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 92%, green 92%);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can also have striped background similar to textbox resizers

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blue { background: #09f; }
.red { background: #f00; }
.orange { background: #f90; }
.green { background: #0c0; }

.button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 45px;
  height: 14px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(255,255,255,.7),
    rgba(255,255,255,.7) 2px,
    transparent 2px,
    transparent 4px
  );
  border-style: 0px solid;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button blue"></div>
<div class="button red"></div>
<div class="button orange"></div>
<div class="button green"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `overflow: hidden` on the container is not an option you can use the pseudo element's bottom border:

```
.container:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: -16px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Adjust margin and border values for your case.